# Database design for a daily maintenance tool

Tags: database, database-design

I'm thinking about the right database design for this requirement.

It's a manual maintenance check. A company can have a maintenance contract comprising HW checks, Sys checks, both or none. The part with the `CommandParameters` worries me especially. The amount/name of the commands can be changed after a while, furthermore they are depending on each company. I was thinking to outsource the `CommandParameters` to it's own table, linking it with the `MaintenanceContract`. The commands would be all in one column, seperated with a delimter. The checkbox and comment line (free-text) are not directly linked with them (see below).  Problem here is, I have to be sure that the amount of delimiters of free-text, checkbox, commands are always the same. I guess it's not possible in the structure, which I have designed below. Would be nice, when you have some other/better ideas.

[image]

Here the database draft:

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  This question seems very broad.  Please improve to it by editing to add focus to particular issues.

Comment: What is MachinesInfo ?

Comment: MachineInfo, its a terminal computer, at the moment, we have only companys with one terminal computer so I decided for a 1:1 relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Errors:**

- The relationship between `COMPANY` and `MACHINE` should me 1:M and not 1:1
- `MAINTENANCE_HW` and `MAINTENANCE_SW` are basically the same
- The column `COMMANDS` violates **NF1** by having multiple values separated by comma
- The relationship between `MAINTENANCE_TYPE` and `MAINTENANCE` should be M:M and not 1:1 for a contract to include both harwd and soft as you state:

**Recommendations:**

- `MAINTENANCE_HW` and `MAINTENANCE_SW` should be merged and then renamed `MAINTENANCE_LOG`
- How do you know which row is hardware and what is software: through the FK with `MAINTENANCE_CONTRACT`->`MAINTENANCE_TYPE`
- `COMMAND_PARAMETER` should be a separate table
- Every item in `MAINTENANCE_LOG` is related to a command parameter

**UPDATE:**

- Since we are normalizing COMMAND_PARAMETER (remember NF1 prohibits habing multiples values in one column. So we create master/detail construction where COMMAND is the master table and COMMAND_PARAMETER has all the parameters of that command. COMMAND basically has a an ID and the description of the command. COMMAND_PARAMETER has an ID and the description of the parameter.
- I also corrected and error in my design. Now `MAINTENANCE_LOG` points to the join table `CONTRACT_MAINTENANCE_TYPE`. This way you know what if it's HW or SW and transitivelly to what contract it belongs to.
- I didn't add all column names because it's a conceptual model, not a physical model. In that stage you still can correct many conceptual errors before actually creating tables. In this stage they are noy yet tables, but entities. Tables with a relationship pointing to a parent entity will have a FK and any other column that you want.

[image: Now <code>MAINTENANCE_LOG</code> points to the join table <code>CONTRACT_MAINTENANCE_TYPE</code>]

**A physical, down-to-earth model:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your new approach. I have currently a few problems to understand your structure. The relationship between MAINTENANCE_CONTRACT and MAINTENANCE_LOG, How I can assign that the MAINTENANCE_LOG is now assigned to Software or Hardware? Furthermore where is exactly the difference between COMMAND and COMMAND_PARAMETER? It could be easier for me, when you would add to those TABLES the attributes.

Comment: I added an update and corrected an error in my design.

Comment: @Matej Added a physical model.

Comment: The physical model helped me alot. Thank you for your help! I will reply maybe later again, when I have some Implementation problems.

Comment: To be sure, I want to ask about MAINTENANCE_LOG / COMMAND_PARAMETER / COMMAND. Could you improve me when I'm wrong: On your database design, there will be for each parameter (command1, free-text, checked/unchecked) an own entry in MAINTENANCE_LOG. The free-text from the maintainer get outsourced in COMMAND_PARAMETER. COMMAND contains only a general description about the COMMAND.

Comment: Yes, COMMAND is just and id and a description. Also COMMAND_PARAMETER is just an id and a description (master/detail here). The free text is in the MAINTENANCE_LOG, I called the column "OBSERVATIONS" instead of free-text. Maintenance log is the main transactional table of your app. A row in that table represents a row in the example report you showed in your question. You could rename it to MAINTENANCE_ACTIVITY if you want.

Comment: But I have really no idea, how i can be more detailed in COMMAND_PARAMETER. Would I break the NF1 rules, when I would link COMMAND directly with MAINTENANCE_LOG?

Comment: You would violate NF1 if you have "parameter1,parameter2,parameter3" as a value in a single column as you would if you dont have a separate PARAMETER entity. One of the consequences of violating NF1 is: *"...I have to be sure that the amount of delimiters of free-text, checkbox, commands are always the same. I guess it's not possible in the structure"*.

Comment: Well, I have another question. Is that a better programming, when you use a join table, instead of adding the MAIN_TYPE_ID directly to the CONTRACT Table?

Comment: @Matej If you do, contracts will be either HW or SYS but never both, and you stated that a contract can be both HW and SYS. M:M relationships require an intermediate table. *"A company can have a maintenance contract comprising HW checks, Sys checks, both or none."*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44610/discussion-between-matej-and-tulains-cordova).